# Paperclip - updating attachment that exists in DB but does not exist on S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

Here we have simple rails model:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base   
has_attached_file :attachment, styles: lambda { |attachment| 
    store_sizes?(attachment) ? { 
      :large => ["414x300>",:png],
      :medium => ["138x100>", :png],
      :for_index => ["180x100", :png],
      :for_preview => ["180x100", :png],
      :thumb => ["62x42>", :png],
      :approval => ['285x122#', :png],
      :origin_png => ['100%', :png]
    } : {}   },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
    :s3_headers => {"Content-Disposition" => "attachment"}
```

[... blah ...]

Due to the complexity of task that I'm given, I have huge amount of attachments in DB but they do not exist on S3 storage.

So the problem is :

```
 a = Attachment.last

 a.attachment
```

this will return fancy url like : http://s3.amazonaws.com/attachments/000/232/055/original/blah.JPG?1370449427

So now I would like to put my file to the attachment attribute :

```
 my_new_file = File.open('/tmp/somefile.jpg')
 a.attachment = my_new_file
 a.attachment.save
```

After successful save I check what was created on amazon and I have only :original style.
The problem is that there should be :large, :medium, :path, :for_index etc. styles.

I tried doing

```
 a.attachment.reprocess!
```

but it forgets all the styles and there's only :original.

How to create all the styles while updating the file on S3?

Answer (score 1):

---

The problem was solvable via:

```
a.attachment.reprocess!
```

but in development.log there was some whining about ImageMagick version.
I've updated imagemagick and all styles were successfully reprocessed.

Sometimes it's good just to write your question to better understand the problem :)